# image not stretch whole page on google chrome

Tags: css, angular

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it!!
I am running Angular 13.
I couldn't stretch the image vertically to the whole page in google chrome:
This is the css:

```
        .pageBg {
        background-image: url('/assets/test.jpg');
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
      }
```

This is the html code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../aqio-web.js"></script>    
</head>
<body class="pageBg">
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <h1>Issue</h1>
                <aqio-web role="issuer" moment="dddc60ea-36a6-4112-a5cd-2ef196da352f"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

```
enter code here
```

Here is the image:
[image]

Comment: Please add a [example]. The code you provided displays the image full screen.

Comment: What issue are you having? Can you upload the background image to imgur or somewhere that isn't local because it may be an image-specific issue. I tried your code and didn't have any issues: https://jsfiddle.net/astombaugh/sf2mLc36/

Comment: The issue I am having is that the image is not fully covering the background. As you can see at the bottom there is a large gap of white space. I played around with different options for the following but it didn't work:background-size: cover;

Comment: Remove the table, you don't need that here. It's not 1990 anymore.